# Linq to SQL latest date

Tags: sql, linq

I have a linq to sql query

```
var items = from p in ctx.bam_Zending_AllInstances
    join q in ctx.bam_Zending_CompletedRelationships 
        on p.ActivityID equals q.ActivityID
    join r in ctx.bam_Prestatie_AllInstances 
        on q.ReferenceData equals r.ActivityID
   where q.ReferenceType == "Activity" && 
         p.Zendingnummer == zenderNr
   orderby r.PrestatieCode
   select new Data.BAMPrestatieInstance
        {
            Aanvaard = r.PrestatieAanvaard,
            Contactnummer = r.ContactNr,
            Foutmelding = r.Foutmelding,
            Identificatie = r.Identificatie,
            Ontvangen = r.PrestatieZendingOntvangen,
            Uitvoerdatum = r.Uitvoerdatum,
            ZendingsNr = p.Zendingnummer,
            PrestatieCode = r.PrestatieCode
        };
```

This returns a list of classes of multiple "r.PrestatieCode"s. "Uitvoerdatum" is a date however, and I need to only have the latest date for each r.PrestatieCode. How should I go about with this? Because I know how to do this in sql, but I can't seem to find the way to do it in linq.

Need this a lot atm actually,

any help is usefull,

thanks a bunch!

Gr

Comment: Can you show me the T-SQL code you would use to do this?

Comment: I want to help you, but can you describe you task a little better? What does it mean "and I need to only have the latest date for each r.PrestatieCode" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a more optimal way, but this will do what you want. With `items` defined as above:

```
var whatYouWant = items
                      .GroupBy(r => r.PrestatieCode)
                      .Select(
                          g => g.Single(
                              r => r.Uitvoerdatum == g.Max(s => s.Uitvoerdatum)
                          )
                       );
```

What this does: First it groups your result set by `Data.BAMPrestatieInstance.PrestatieCode`. Then, from each group with the same `Data.BAMPrestatieInstance.PrestatieCode`, it extracts the maximum `Data.BAMPrestatieInstance.Uitvoerdatum` and then finds the unique item with `Data.BAMPrestatieInstance.Uitvoerdatum` equal to that maximum date. If there is not a unique item with `Data.BAMPrestatieInstance.Uitvoerdatum` equal to that maximum date you can alter accordingly (use `Where` instead of `Single`, for example).

Let me know if I misunderstood your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it in SQL, you could write it like:

```
yourDataContext.ExecuteQuery<Data.BAMPrestatieInstance>(
    "<sql query>");
```